# JavaScript: I'm practicing recursion in JavaScript and and am attempting to return true or false from a conditional but am seeing nothing

Tags: javascript, recursion

The title pretty much says it all. I know there are others ways to determine whether a string is a palindrome (e.g., turning the string to an array, reversing it, joining it, and comparing that resulting string to the original), but I'm just trying to work with recursion for now. The only scenarios that return expected values are the following:

```
isPalindrome("a"); // true
isPalindrome("aalsdjlkjdfsdkjf"); // false
```

This returns nothing whatsoever:

```
isPalindrome("amma"); //
```

Here's my function's code:

```
function isPalindrome (str) {
  if (str.length <= 1) {
    return true;
  } else if (str.charAt(0) == str.slice(-1)) {
    isPalindrome(str.slice(1,-1));
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: The only case where you don't return anything is if `str.charAt(0) == str.slice(-1)` is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second branch of your conditional, you want to return the result:

```
return isPalindrome(str.slice(1,-1));
```

Otherwise it simply completes the recursive call, exits the `if` statement, and returns `undefined` (since it encounters no `return` statement before the end of the function).

Comment: Hey, Ted--has anyone told you how much you rock today? Because you do. You rock! Thank you! I will mark this as the answer in ten minutes.